# How to add icons to MUI Input base?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI InputBase and I am trying to add an icon into the input field, but when I try, the icon is above the input field rather than inside the field.

```
const StyledInput = styled('input')(
    ({ theme }) => `
    width: 505px;
    height: 56px;
    font-size: 24px;
    fontFamily: 'Roboto';
    fontWeight: 500;

    letterSpacing: '0.15px';
    background: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    
  `
);

export const CustomInput = React.forwardRef(function CustomInput(
    props: InputUnstyledProps,
    ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>
) {
    return (
        <InputUnstyled
            components={{ Input: StyledInput }}
            startAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <SearchOutlined fontSize="medium" color="info" />
                </InputAdornment>
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
        />
    );
});
```

I didn't use the normal text field because when I set the background of the text field to white as the page background is pink the icon and the text are not visible.

[The field looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Jkc.png)

[Its suppose to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db9ST.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Is InputUnstyled an MUI component? It probably doesn't have styling to render the children inline